# Use the value that a function returns as the name of a new Array

Tags: java

Good I am trying to create a function that generates new Array, and trying to use a getter method that returns a name for example ArrayD5, ArrayD10 and use these as the name of the new arrays to generate.

I have tried to do this:

`int length = 5;`

`String (SeatIbiza.nombres(length))[] = new String[length];`

```
String nombres (int length) {
    
    return "ArrayD"+length;
}
```

Comment: and  what's your question?

Comment: This looks like an XY problem to me. What is your *actual* problem? With other words: *why* do you want that?

Comment: Please see [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for a way to declare something like *e.g.*

`String "ArrayD" + 2`

so that you have a variable

`String ArrayD2`

then this is not possible in Java. Dynamic naming of variables is not supported.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think if that's possible. The variable names are required to be declared during compile time in JAVA and dynamic naming isn't supported... yet.
Correct me if I'm wrong as I'm still learning about JAVA